# how to have different background images in two different pages in angular2?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a angular 2 application on which i have to use seperate background images on home page and other pages, i have applied image on index.html  to have a background image but i need to add different image on different pages.
This is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/slideshow.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="ui" href="resources/css/semantic.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="ui" href="resources/css/angularSwitch.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="ui" href="resources/css/main.css" />
  <link href="resources/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="resources/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/chart-data.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/easypiechart.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/easypiechart-data.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  <script>
<!--Icons-->
<script src="resources/js/lumino.glyphs.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url("resources/static/pic/slide_1.jpg");" >

  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

What about applying a background image at the component level instead of inside the index.html?  Then each component could have a different background image.  You could even have a separate css file that includes a snippet of code like this:

```
body { background-image: url("resources/static/pic/slide_1.jpg"); }
```

and include it in each component "styleUrls" that you want that background image to appear on.  Use a different css for the components you want a different image on.

Hope this helps

Comment: It is not possible, there is a `body` element only in the main html, the other ones are just sequences which will be placed inside the body, and adding in each css of the components `body{..}` sequence will just create some issues related to how elements will be shown =/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this like you can have different background images on different components of your app. To do this please follow the instructions given below.

In your main `css` file that is `style.css` give the height 100% to the body & html please refer the below code.

**Style.css**

```
body,html{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now in your components css file that is `namespace.component.css` file add the below code

```
.component-body{
    background-image: url(/assets/images/background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now make sure that you are having all the contents inside the div contains this class. You can have the dive classes & the css into their css files accordingly. For more information you can refer [this link](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/css/background-image/)